# Setting up Compass in PhpStorm

Tags: sass, compass-sass, phpstorm

There's a few posts about this on here, but I couldn't find any for the latest PHPStorm version that claims to support Compass.

So from my project root I have:

/public/assets/css

/public/assets/scss

/public/assets/config.rb

which contains:

```
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "css"
sass_dir = "scss"
images_dir = "img"
javascripts_dir = "js"
```

My compass executable is set to: /usr/bin/compass
and the config path is set to: path-to-project/public/assets/config.rb

I've also set up PhpStorm to compile the scss files into the /public/assets/css folder

In one scss file I have

```
@import "compass";
```

and I get this error:

```
/usr/bin/compass compile /private/var/virt/budget-forklifts/public/assets compile /private/var/virt/budget-forklifts/public/assets/scss
You must compile individual stylesheets from the project directory.
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: similar setup works fine for me. The error indicates that the compiler is executed from th wrong folder or the configuration is incorrect... Please attach a screenshot of your compass file watcher. Make sure to make it large enough so that all arguments are visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out if others have this same issue:

You just have to disable your scss file watcher when you enable the compass scss one. I guess they both run at once and get confused.

Comment: doesn't look like a right answer - having both watchers enabled doesn't cause such issues. SASS watcher doesn't affect compass in any way. And the error shows that this is a compass watcher that's being executed